# Can't find dependent libraries when trying to run deeplearning4j with CUDA

Tags: cuda, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I'm attempting to run a neural network built using dl4j using the GPU. The code works fine when using the native platform dependency, but when I switch to using CUDA, execution fails with an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ...\cuda-8.0-6.0-1.3-windows-x86_64.jar\org\bytedeco\javacpp\windows-x86_64\jnicuda.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Here is what I have in my build.gradle:

```
//    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version: '0.9.1'
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-cuda-8.0-platform', version: '0.9.1'
```

Here are the dependencies showin in IDEA:

[image: Dependencies]

I was able to install the CUDA Toolkit and build the examples just fine. Running deviceQuery shows that my CUDA Driver / Runtime version is 9.1, is this a problem since the nd4j-cuda-8.0-platform references 8.0? Not sure, since the version is 0.9.1, which matches my CUDA version and there does not seem to be a 9.0 platform available.

Is there something additional that I'm missing? If so, how do I troubleshoot/resolve this?

Comment: Attempted adding nvcc.exe to src/main/resources as described here: https://nd4j.org/getstarted.html#gpu

Still the same error.

Comment: Hmm, based on :https://nd4j.org/gpu_native_backends.html

"We support Cuda 7.5 and 8.0 at the moment."

Sounds like CUDA 9 isn't supported and isn't backwards compatible?

Comment: Based on https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/issues/2285, CUDA 9 is supported on master. However, still the same error with 
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-cuda-8.0-platform', version: '0.9.2-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: CodeMonkeyCharlie could you share your `gradle` script. I'm facing the same issue but haven't been able to resolve it. Also, you mentioned you installed CUDA 8. Did you mean CUDA Toolkit 8.0 GA2 from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out there are a few issues. Firstly, deeplearning4j's current release does not support CUDA 9, which I had naively installed thinking the latest and greatest is the best. CUDA 9 is supported on the latest snapshot, which I tried out, but apparently due to some issue with Gradle and snapshots, was unable to resolve the issue.

Ultimately I uninstalled everything relating to CUDA from my PC and installed CUDA 8 from scratch, restarted the computer, and now things seem to be working.